# Converting to multilevel column from normalized column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv in below format,

```
print rfd.iloc[:5,:5]   

                            Sub-division   January 2010 Actual   January  2010 Normal   January 2011 Actual   February  2010 Actual 
0            Andaman and Nicobar Islands                   98.2                   53.7                 222.5                     5.8
1                       Arunachal Pradesh                   0.4                   50.1                  37.6                    10.0
2                     Assam and Meghalaya                   0.2                   16.4                   9.0                     3.4
3  Nagaland,Manipur, Mizoram, and Tripura                   0.9                   13.7                   7.9                    10.9
4     Sub-Himalayan,West Bengal & Sikkim                    1.7                   26.6                   7.1                     6.4
```

How to convert it to multi-level columns. First level would be Year, then Month and type.

```
rfd.columns
Out[89]: 
Index([u'Sub-division ', u'January 2010 Actual ', u'January  2010 Normal ',
       u'January 2011 Actual ', u'February  2010 Actual ',
     ....
       u'December  2010 Normal ', u'   December 2011 Actual '],
      dtype='object')
```

I tried something like this `rfd.columns = rfd.columns.str.split(" ")` then data frame became `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. If its just one file I could update it in csv and load but it is repeatable process so looking for some solution in which I can iterate over the files.

Adding two row of dictionary,

```
{'April  2010 Normal': {0: 81.5, 1: 278.80000000000001},
 'April 2010 Actual': {0: 12.699999999999999, 1: 245.80000000000001},
 'April 2011 Actual': {0: 83.700000000000003, 1: 114.7},
 'August  2010 Actual': {0: 550.0, 1: 343.30000000000001},
 'August  2010 Normal': {0: 403.80000000000001, 1: 359.89999999999998},
 'August 2011 Actual': {0: 513.0, 1: 225.80000000000001},
 'December  2010 Normal': {0: 145.5, 1: 38.399999999999999},
 'December 2010 Actual': {0: 254.40000000000001, 1: 6.0},
 'December 2011 Actual': {0: 246.30000000000001, 1: 10.300000000000001},
 'February  2010 Actual': {0: 5.7999999999999998, 1: 10.0},
 'February  2010 Normal': {0: 29.199999999999999, 1: 98.0},
 'February  2011 Actual': {0: 81.900000000000006, 1: 36.799999999999997},
 'January  2010 Normal': {0: 53.700000000000003, 1: 50.100000000000001},
 'January 2010 Actual': {0: 98.200000000000003, 1: 0.40000000000000002},
 'January 2011 Actual': {0: 222.5, 1: 37.600000000000001},
 'July  2010 Normal': {0: 407.69999999999999, 1: 536.10000000000002},
 'July 2010 Actual': {0: 522.10000000000002, 1: 426.0},
 'July 2011 Actual': {0: 575.79999999999995, 1: 553.5},
 'June  2010 Normal': {0: 438.60000000000002, 1: 500.39999999999998},
 'June  2011 Actual': {0: 418.39999999999998, 1: 336.80000000000001},
 'June 2010 Actual': {0: 435.0, 1: 397.30000000000001},
 'March   2010 Normal': {0: 25.0, 1: 179.69999999999999},
 'March  2010 Normal': {0: 20.5, 1: 164.40000000000001},
 'March  2011 Actual': {0: 305.5, 1: 121.5},
 'March 2010 Actual': {0: 0.40000000000000002, 1: 143.59999999999999},
 'May  2010 Actual': {0: 310.69999999999999, 1: 273.80000000000001},
 'May  2010 Normal': {0: 358.5, 1: 291.89999999999998},
 'May 2011 Actual': {0: 305.69999999999999, 1: 157.80000000000001},
 'November  2010 Normal': {0: 253.69999999999999, 1: 45.799999999999997},
 'November 2010 Actual': {0: 281.39999999999998, 1: 59.700000000000003},
 'November 2011 Actual': {0: 126.0, 1: 19.800000000000001},
 'October  2010 Actual': {0: 415.19999999999999, 1: 84.400000000000006},
 'October  2010 Normal': {0: 296.69999999999999, 1: 183.0},
 'October  2011 Actual': {0: 183.80000000000001, 1: 46.799999999999997},
 'September  2010 Normal': {0: 432.39999999999998, 1: 371.60000000000002},
 'September 2010 Actual': {0: 261.30000000000001, 1: 407.39999999999998},
 'September 2011 Actual': {0: 770.89999999999998, 1: 262.0},
 'Sub-division': {0: 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands ', 1: 'Arunachal Pradesh'},
 'october  2010 Normal': {0: 297.80000000000001, 1: 159.09999999999999}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not the 'best way' to do this and probably not very optimal

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')
b = a.set_index('Sub-division').unstack().reset_index()
c = b['level_0']

d = c.str.extract('(?P<Month>[A-Za-z]*) +(?P<Year>[0-9][\w\d]*) +(?P<Level>[A-Za-z]*)')

e = pd.concat([b[['Sub-division',0]], d], axis=1)

f = e.set_index(['Sub-division', 'Year', 'Month', 'Level'])

f = f.unstack(['Year','Month','Level'])

f.columns = f.columns.droplevel(0)

f.sortlevel(level=0,axis=1)
```

But it does what you want, the function you are looking for probably is 
pd.str.extract

It outputs this:

```
Year                                      2010                   2011
Month                                 February January        January
Level                                   Actual  Actual Normal  Actual
Sub-division                                                         
Andaman and Nicobar Islands                5.8    98.2   53.7   222.5
Arunachal Pradesh                         10.0     0.4   50.1    37.6
Assam and Meghalaya                        3.4     0.2   16.4     9.0
Nagaland,Manipur, Mizoram and Tripura     10.9     0.9   13.7     7.9
Sub-Himalayan,West Bengal & Sikkim         6.4     1.7   26.6     7.1
```

You have special tools in pandas to deal with time series so there may be a better representation thatn what you see here.

Comment: Thanks, for the post. I'm not really looking for efficient way. I get this error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` for `f = f.unstack(['Year','Month','Level'])`. +1 for bring until this point

Comment: Works ok for me. I'm using pandas 0.17.0 maybe different version? My only other idea is that the initial dataframe is different from yours. Anyway last lines are purely cosmetic.

Comment: mine `0.16.2` may be. I used the same data that I posted as dict. `a = pandas.DataFrame(copypaste)`

Comment: Your dictionary have duplicated entries (March 2010 and October 2010 which is also wrongly written). I have edited the regexp so it now accepts several spaces between words as in your dictionary. If you remove the duplicated entries it now works fine.